# Converting Varchar Date to Datetime

Tags: .net, datetime, converters, datetimepicker, varchar

I know when you see topic you said this question asked before but mine is different.
I have a db and a table Date1. Date1 is varchar and i keep date in dd.mm.yyyy format(104). 
in my form i have two `datetimepicker`: `date1` and `date2`. when click submit button i cant get information between two dates. it gives conversion error. I wrote this sql command. can you solve problem?

```
SqlDataAdapter adtr = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from EvrakArsiv where 
CONVERT(DATETIME,KAYITTARIHI,104)>='"+tbIlkTarih.Value.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")+"' and 
CONVERT(DATETIME,KAYITTARIHI,104)<='"+tbSonTarih.Value.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")+"'", 
connection);
```

Comment: Date1=KAYITTARIHI in SQL DB.                                        tbIlkTarih = Date1, tbSonTarih=Date2 at form

Comment: Any reason *why* the column is a varchar in the database and not a date?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET the `mm` in a `DateTime` format string means ***minutes***, not months. You want `MM`, with capital M. Otherwise you get the minutes part of your `System.DateTime` which is likely `00` (whole hour).

So change:

```
tbIlkTarih.Value.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")
```

into:

```
tbIlkTarih.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

and similarly for the other control.

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).